# Can't access dl, dt or dd with XPath for one specific webpage (Symantec's virus database)

Tags: html, xpath

I'm new to using xpath and trying to extract data from the webpage http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2000-122015-2208-99

The xpaths `//dl`, `//dt` and `//dd` return empty lists for me, while `//h1`, `//h2`, `//div`, `//a`, `//p` and everything else I could think to try work as expected. The `//dl`, `//dt` and `//dd` xpaths work perfectly for other webpages with the relevant tags.

Why does this happen for this webpage, and how can I access the dl, dt and dd nodes?

The relevant section of my (python) code is

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2000-122015-2208-99?'
htmlp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(htmlp.text)

dlList = tree.xpath('//dl')

#How I'm checking to see if dlList is empty
print len(dlList)
print dlList[0]
```

It seems to work when I have anything other than `//dl`, `//dt` or `//dd`. `//div/dl` etc also doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the code, in which ever language you are using, you already have for this?  I seem to be able to access those nodes fine using //div/dl

Comment: I've added my code. I also can't make it work with `//div/dl`. Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated.